# Live chart completely refreshing in amCharts

Tags: javascript, ajax, amcharts

I would like to create a live chart using amChart.js, So I'm using ajax for live chart update. If I called the ajax page in `setInterval` the chart is completely refreshing. Actually, I need to change the data only.

Please check my script from [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qkahxobn/).

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your fiddle does not work, because of the php stuff in the js part. Can you fix this, that we have a working example which reproduces your error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "change the data only" if you mean transitioning to new points or values, then you can't replace the entire array. Replacing the entire array will always cause a complete redraw. Note that you usually don't need to call `invalidateData` when replacing the entire array.

If you want your chart to transition to the new values, then you have to change how you update your data. If you update the data in-place and call `invalidateRawData`, AmCharts will animate from one  Transitions only occur if you're updating data in place and calling `invalidateRawData` or if you're using `addData` to add data to the array. Not knowing what your data looks like in your ajax requests, you'll need to figure out the best approach.

You can read more about how to manage incremental/transitional updates [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Incremental_updates).

Comment: Thank you, please check the screenshot https://imgur.com/UqSbdh7. It's overlapping the tooltip. If you don't mind please let me know how to update?